# Read and print mean for columns' values in rows

Tags: perl

I would like to read and print mean for columns' values in every row (there may be 75,000 rows) for different groups (6 groups consisting of 5 or 10 columns). Could you please help in writing the script. I would be glad and highly appreciate for your kindness.

Regards,
Momocha

Comment: Some sample data would be useful. I don't think it's entirely clear how those 6 groups are defined.

Answer (score 2):

These steps that will help you achieve your goal:

1. Read the content of the file. You can use [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) for CSV or [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://p3rl.org/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel) for Excel files.
2. Store the desired groups in an array.
3. Use [Statistics::Basic](http://p3rl.org/Statistics%3a%3aBasic) to get the mean.

If you are having a problem using these modules, feel free to ask.